# How come my for loop skips one of my scanner function when there is no conditional statement

Tags: java

So I have this code that I am working on that is supposed to calculate a user GPA depending on the input and I have made a method to ask the user a series of questions and my goal is to get a output like this

Course 1:

Class: *user input*

Is AP: *user input*

Grade: *user input*

Course 2:

Class: *user input*

Is AP: *user input*

Grade: *user input*

Course 3:

Class: *user input*

Is AP: *user input*

Grade: *user input*

Course 4:

Class: *user input*

Is AP: *user input*

Grade: *user input*

to do this I have made this code

```
public static void askQuestions() 
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) 
    {
    System.out.println("Course " + i + ":");
    System.out.print("    Class:  ");
    String courseName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("    is AP:  ");
    String answer = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("    Grade:  ");
    int Grade = input.nextInt();
    }
  }
```

but my result is this

Course 1:

Class: *user input*

Is AP: *user input*

Grade: *user input*

Course 2:

Class:         Is AP: *user input*

Grade: *user input*

Course 3:

Class:         Is AP: *user input*

Grade: *user input*

Course 4:

Class:         Is AP: *user input*

Grade: *user input*

like the first loop is fine but the rest of the loop is not. what am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input.nextInt(); reads only integer, and new line symbol(\n) still remains, so subsequent nextLine reada this \n,
\n is enter press

It's looks like this

Class: A\n(reads all)

Is AP: something \n(reads all)

Grade: 23\n(reads 23 only)

Class: \n(from prev input)

you should write like this Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine())

Comment: okok so basically when an enter is pressed there is an invisible "\n" in the code and the nextLine code reads "\n" as a string?

Comment: Yes, something like this.

Comment: So, nextLine uses \n as delimiter, nextInt reads number by number

Comment: for example, if scanner gets 1 2 3 \n 4 5 6, first nextLine call returns 1 2 3, second 4 5 6

Comment: You can also write Integer Grade = input.nextInt(); input.nextLine(); to skip \n